# How to deep compare two javascript objects and return all the differences including new added arrays and with the same original format?

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two javascript objects. How can I list all the differences using optimized code?

I tried few plugins deep-diff & lodash as well.Lodash is returning me difference of the same line but not any other added field.

```
const a = {
"id":1,
"name":xyz
}

const b = {
"id":1,
"name":xyz abc,
"address":pqr
}
```

I expect the output: `{"name":xyz abc","address":pqr}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Object.keys(a).forEach(x => { if (Object.keys(b).every(y => b[y] !== a[x])) { diff[x] = a[x] } })
    Object.keys(b).forEach(x => { if (Object.keys(a).every(y => a[y] !== b[x])) { diff[x] = b[x] } })
    console.log(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want using lodash functions.

https://gist.github.com/Yimiprod/7ee176597fef230d1451

Comment: Hey... I tried this earlier but it wasn't returning newly added arrays or any other added field...It was returning difference only on the same line.